# what is the difference between lucene.NET and DBMS?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene.net

I am building a search engine and I finished the first phase which is spidering (fetching html documents and parsing each document to get the other links). Now I must index the content of html documents. First of all I decided to use DBMS (like SQL Server) for this purpose but I found another library called Lucene.NET.

What is the difference between lucene.NET and SQL Server and which one is better to use to index html documents? I read alot about Lucene.Net and I surprised that it gives better performance than SQL Server. Can any one explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is a general purpose RDBMS that is *not* optimized for very fast text indexing (yes, it has full text indexes, but it does lots of other things at the same time).

Lucene.NET is not a RDBMS and its main function is fast text indexing.

Not that surprising it is better at it than SQL Server.